# This Keyword Usage in element And Parameter

Tags: javascript, this, keyword

I am learning **JavaScript** event my point is that '`this`' keyword is used for object or global object but in this code this keyword is used in element in function callback parameter why ?

**Q1)** How we can use 'this' in element `onClick` event in this code ?

**Q2)** Secondly sometime i put this keyword in function argument parameter so error generate '`Unexpected Token`'.

Kindly help for these two question.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">

<div class="d1" onclick="highlight(this)">1 
    <div class="d2" onclick="highlight(this)">2
        <div class="d3" onclick="highlight(this)">3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function highlight(elem) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor='yellow'
    alert(elem.className)
    elem.style.backgroundColor = ''
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, use punctuation to structure your sentences. It's hard to understand you otherwise.

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md are good sources to read about `this` in Javascript.

Comment: did not you see the code below in this code in div section function called at onclick event and in the parameter of that function using 'this' keyword, so my point why we use 'this' keyword here, how you can explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

Q1) How we can use 'this' in element onClick event in this code ?
A)'this' in HTML refers to the HTML element that received the event.in your case the element is 'div'

Q2) Secondly sometime i put this keyword in function argument parameter so error generate 'Unexpected Token'.
A) i see 'this' is an implicit param that will be passed automatically when we call a function based on the object , the function call is attached to . so i feel , there will be a conflict b/w function argument's 'this' & implicit 'this'